# Reference argument has empty values

Tags: c++, reference

I have a function that takes a reference argument. It also returns a boolean to show if it succeeded or not. So:

```
bool foo(myClass& obj)
```

I pass a value to this function through another function with the following line:

```
success = foo(obj);
```

However, when I debugged my program, I realized that the object was initialized correctly before coming to the function call, but then its value inside the foo function ended up empty, with all values at their default. I'm not sure why the reference pass did not work as intended.

Comment: Please delete the question if you no longer intend to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm an idiot. This function call was inside a for loop, and I accidentally used the comparison value in the array index rather than the for loop iterator. Elementary mistake, I know.